# How to read byte array from file in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

When I want read bytes from a file in Java, I can do like this:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(...);
while((int b = is.read()) != -1){
    //...analysis the bytes.
}
```

And how do it in Haskell? I don't see any function witch can read bytes module System.IO and Data.ByteString.

Comment: https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.8/bytestring-0.10.8.2/Data-ByteString.html#v:readFile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `readFile`

```
import Data.ByteString(readFile)

main = do 
    content <-  Data.ByteString.readFile "path/to/file"
    print content
```

It read the file and print it content on screen.

Comment: It read `ByteString` which is in fact array of `Word8` which is smart way to name byte.

Comment: So you mean I don't need to import `ByteString` to read `Word8` which like `Byte` in Java ?

Comment: Easiest way to check that is to try, but yes, you don't need to import it.

Comment: @talex the readFile in prelude reads into a `String`. It appears the question asker wants to read into bytes rather then characters. I think `ByteString` is the correct thing for that.

Comment: @Potato44 then proper (`Data.ByteString`) function should be imported.